# createkeysand certificate aws javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I am implementing the following code using javascript in browser to create certificate and key pair:

```
    var iot = new AWS.Iot();
    function createCert(){
        var params = {
            setAsActive:false
        };
        iot.createKeysAndCertificate(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else     console.log(data);           // successful response
        });
    };
```

and I am getting the ERROR as :

UnknownOperationException: null
    at Object.s [as extractError] (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.106.0.min.js:42:24512)
    at constructor.o (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.106.0.min.js:42:29401)

Please help me in resolving this error.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I had configured AWS for dynamoDB and the endpoint of AWS.Iot was not updated.
Now, it works!!!